# General Solutions of ODE $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+\beta x^2y=-\alpha x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solutions of this ODE $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+\beta x^2y=-\alpha x^2$$

I already found the complementary function of this ODE with bessels function but I can't seem to find the solutions for the particular function.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$x^2u''(x)+x~u'(x)+bx^2u(x)=-ax^2\\\text{equivalently}\\x~u''(x)+u'(x)+bx~u(x)=-ax$$
If we look at the homogeneous equation
$$x~u''(x)+u'(x)+bx~u(x)=0$$
We do a change of variable. Let $s(x)=\sqrt{b}~x$ and let $U(s(x))=u$. Then
$$x~u''(x)+u(x)+bx~u(x)=0\implies bx~U''(s(x))+\sqrt{b}~U'(s(x))+bx~U(s(x))=0 \\ \implies \sqrt{b}~s~U''(s)+\sqrt{b}~U'(s)+\sqrt{b}~s~U(s)=0 \\ \implies s~U''(s)+U'(s)+s~U(s)=0\\\implies U(s)=c_1 J_0(s)+c_2Y_0(s) \\ \implies u_{\mathrm h}(x)=U(s(x))=c_1J_0(\sqrt{b}~x)+c_2Y_0(\sqrt{b}~x)$$
When it comes to finding a particular solution, we can look for constant solutions, which leads us to the equation
$$bx~u(x)=-ax\\\implies u_{\mathrm p}(x)=\frac{-a}{b}$$
Generally, then
$$u(x)=u_{\mathrm h}(x)+u_{\mathrm p}(x)=\frac{-a}{b}+c_1J_0(\sqrt{b}~x)+c_2Y_0(\sqrt{b}~x)$$